# Failed to create a selector / Unable to establish loopback connection / Connection timed out

Tags: java, socket.io, netty

I am running a Java socket.io server (com.corundumstudio.socketio implementation), it used to work OK, but now, just after I start() the server, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to c
reate a selector.
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(A
bstractNioSelector.java:338)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(Abstrac
tNioSelector.java:96)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.<init>(AbstractN
ioWorker.java:51)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.<init>(NioWorker.java:45
)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.createWorker(NioWork
erPool.java:45)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.createWorker(NioWork
erPool.java:28)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.newWorker(Ab
stractNioWorkerPool.java:99)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.init(Abstrac
tNioWorkerPool.java:69)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(NioWorkerPool
.java:39)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(NioWorkerPool
.java:33)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<ini
t>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:149)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<ini
t>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:131)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<ini
t>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:115)
        at com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer.start(SocketIOServer.java:
76)
        at biu_nlp_net.CommonSocketIOServer.start(CommonSocketIOServer.java:67)
        at biu_nlp_net.LexicalEntailmentServer.main(LexicalEntailmentServer.java
:188)
**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection**
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(A
bstractNioSelector.java:336)
        ... 15 more
**Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
```

I run this with Java 7 on Windows 2003.

Comment: This question helped me solve my same problem. I determined that there was a network configuration issue related to my VPN. Restarting windows solved my issue as well.

Comment: @Jpnh it is good to see that even a "too localized" question can still help future visitors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after rebooting the Windows machine. Probably a tired server...

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a firewall problem... You will need to check in detail here.

Comment: I don't think so, because sometimes it does work OK.

Comment: Definitely not. The selector doesn't use any network resources except a local socket created on I think 127.0.0.2. Nothing to do with any firewall.